# How to use $this->db->like and $this->db->where at the same time in codeigniter search form

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Hello guys I am trying to learn CI by making a Job Search project in codeigniter. I am trying to make multiple input field job search engine in it. I have three fields in the form. My form is below
[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X59jp.png)

My controller code is this :

```
  class Search extends CI_Controller{

    public function normal(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_keywords', 'Job Keywords', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

             $viewdata['main_view'] = 'home';
             $this->load->view('layout/main', $viewdata);

        }
        else{
          $search_term = $this->input->post('job_keywords');
          $location = $this->input->post('job_location');
          $type = $this->input->post('job_type');
          $searchdata['search_results'] = $this->search_model->default_search($search_term, $location, $type);

                $searchdata['main_view'] = 'search_page';
          $this->load->view('layout/main', $searchdata);
        }
    }
```

}

My model is:

```
    public function default_search($search_term, $location="", $type){

    $searchterm = $search_term;

    $this->db->like('job_title', $searchterm);
    $this->db->or_like('job_description', $search_term);

    $this->db->where('type_id', $type); 

    if($location!= ""){
       $this->db->like('location_id', $location);   
    }



    $res = $this->db->get('jobs');

    if($res->num_rows() >= 1){
        return $res->result();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am getting the search results when I am just using $this->$db->like() and $this->$db->or_like() but when I am using a $this->$db->where() the query doesn't follow the WHERE clause. When I remove $this->$db->or_like(), it works fine but not with two like clause. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong. Thank you.

[Job table structure with 2 rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jc6M.png)

Comment: One more thing I am comparing two columns in the database with my first field in the form. The location field is optional.

Comment: Try to display the last executed query like this `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: I am getting this - SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `job_title` LIKE '%frontend%' ESCAPE '!' OR `job_description` LIKE '%frontend%' ESCAPE '!' AND `type_id` = 'pt'

Comment: But the type_id condition is not playing any role as if its not there at all

Comment: You are sure that you have an id 'pt' in string ?

Comment: Yes I have kept the type_id (it means JOB TYPE ID ) as string in my table for now. I have added an image at the end of my question of my  table structure. I am using the 'pt' for part time and 'ft' for fulltime job.

Comment: The id should be unique for every row of your table. Try to execute the query  in your PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I am getting the same wrong result. I want that the 'frontend developer' job must only show when the type_id(that means the job type) is 'ft' but it is showing when the type_id is even 'pt' in the where clause but when I remove the second LIKE condition from the query, it works fine. 2 LIKE conditions are somehow creating some problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build the query that way :

```
$query = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE (job_title LIKE '%".$jobtitle."%' OR job_description LIKE '%".$jobdescription."%') AND type_id = '".$type_id."' ");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
  foreach ($query->result() as $row){
     //do some code
    }
  }
```

Try to pass the 3 parameters in the function : `public function default_search(..., $jobtitle, $jobdescription,$type_id)`

Comment: Just few minutes back I did the same thing but a bit differently and it solved the problem. The problem was that I should have kept the OR seperated from the AND in the query using paranthesis.       I did this $this->db->where("(`job_title` LIKE '%" . $search_term . "%' ESCAPE '!' OR `job_description` LIKE '%" . $search_term . "%' ESCAPE '!') AND `type_id` = '" . $type ."'");
    
  $res = $this->db->get('jobs');

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful